Hose valve in the middle of lawn
My wife would like a hose connector (or a couple) in the middle of the yard, as she often needs a lot of water in certain spots far away from the house and does not want to pull a 100ft hose and later reel it back (damaging flower beds that are on the way).  My plan is to lay down sprinkler tubing (e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-4-in-x-100-ft-IPS-100-PSI-NSF-Pipe-X2-75100100/205903417), connect it to a hose valve at the side of the house, and terminate it with a PVC pipe and a valve.  To winterize, I plan to blow into it with a compressor as I have done over 2 seasons with our sprinkler system.
Is that a good plan?  Any advice?

IT's a good plan. Be sure you get the correct parts when working with PVC and poly pipe.    3/4 NPT looks like it will attach to a hose but it will not, you need 3/4 MHT.

Thank you for the advice!

Assuming the plan is to have the mid-yard spigot above ground, and a garden hose left at that location, you should mount it on at least a 4x4 pressure treated post and place some large (at least 50lb) rocks all around it.  Otherwise it is guaranteed to be destroyed within a year by lawn mowers, balls, etc.   There is a (expensive) solution where the spigot and hose are in an underground chamber.

The valve at the house-end can be indoors.  You probably need a backflow preventer since it will be underground attached to your water supply.  If you can tee off your sprinkler system, after the back flow, after the compressor attachment, and before the valve box, that would be much easier.  Or here's an idea:  tee off the valve box with a new sprinkler valve in the valve box and a smart controller.  Then you don't need a valve at the far end, she can turn it on with her phone.   The hose connector can be underground and the hose can hang on a little stake that doesn't need protection.

The "hose valve at the side of the house" is in fact an offshoot the sprinkler system, after the compressor connector (which is inside the house) and before the valve box.  The guy who replaced my sprinkler valves installed it saying "don't worry about it, it's for me".  Most likely, he thought I'd call him to winterize the system, and wanted to attach his compressor outside of the house.  I'll think about a smart valve.  Is there a way to check whether that thing is before or after the backflow preventer?

"Lay down" equals "bury?"

Yes, why?......

If the hose valve you connect to has a vacuum breaker, it will not be rated for continuous pressure. It would be best to repipe the hose valve so that the new line tees off before the hose valve with a separate ball valve.
